# Jquery Inline editing with multiple combo boxes

Tags: jquery

Having a easyui jquery datagrid supporting inline editing. The row has 4 fields to be edited, two text boxes and two combo boxes. The two text boxes and even one combo box editing is working fine.

But when editing another combo box, conflict arises between the combo boxes and the result is not appropriate. ie) The value selected in one drop down get set in the another one.

Looks like some configuration issue but not able to figure out the exact root cause.

Can any one point out some direction where I can find some example where two or more combo boxes are used in inline editing.

Below is the code snippet. This is my datagrid.

```html
<table id="result_grid" class="easyui-datagrid" 
   data-options="url:'conf.json',method:'get',onClickCell: onClickCell">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th data-options="field:'gen',editor:'numberbox'">Generation</th>
   <th data-options="field:'comments',editor:'textbox'">Comments</th>
   <th data-options="field:'id',
      formatter:function(value,row){
       return row.txt;
                        },
                        editor:{
                            type:'combobox',
                            options:{
                                valueField:'id',
                                textField:'txt',
                                method:'get',
                                url:'nonCache.json',
                                required:true        
                            }
                        }">Nonvolatile Cache</th>
   <th data-options="field:'id',
      formatter:function(value,row){
       return row.txt;
                        },
                        editor:{
                            type:'combobox',
                            options:{
                                valueField:'id',
                                textField:'txt',
                                method:'get',
                                url:'mktName.json',
                                required:true        
                            }
                        }">Marketing Name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

This is the corresponding java script taken from jquery([Jquery demo](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/?plugin=DataGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=)) example.

```js
var editIndex = undefined;
function endEditing() {
 if (editIndex == undefined) {
  return true;
 }
 if ($('#result_grid').datagrid('validateRow', editIndex)) {
  var ed = $('#result_grid').datagrid('getEditor', { 
          index : editIndex, field : 'id' 
        });
  var txt = $(ed.target).combobox('getText');
  $('#result_grid').datagrid('getRows')[editIndex]['txt'] = txt;
  $('#result_grid').datagrid('endEdit', editIndex);
  editIndex = undefined;
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}
function onClickCell(index, field) {
 if (editIndex != index) {
  if (endEditing()) {
   $('#result_grid').datagrid('selectRow', index).datagrid('beginEdit', index);
   var ed = $('#result_grid').datagrid('getEditor', {index : index, field : field});
   ($(ed.target).data('textbox') ? $(ed.target).textbox('textbox')
     : $(ed.target)).focus();
   editIndex = index;
  } else {
   $('#result_grid').datagrid('selectRow', editIndex);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet given in the easyui jquery demo page is not correct. The correct code can be obtained from [Github code](https://github.com/ni-jmatthiesen/jQuery-EasyUI).

I have edited the endEditing function as below,

combo 1:

```
var ed = $('#ana_rev_grid').datagrid('getEditor', {
    index : editIndex,
    field : 'mktNameId'
});
$('#ana_rev_grid').datagrid('getRows')[editIndex]['mktNameTxt'] = $(
                ed.target).combobox('getText');
```

Combo 2:

```
var ped = $('#ana_rev_grid').datagrid('getEditor', {
    index : editIndex,
    field : 'prodTypeId'
});
$('#ana_rev_grid').datagrid('getRows')[editIndex]['prodTypeTxt'] = $(
                ped.target).combobox('getText');
```